# How to serve bundles from another application w/ ASP.NET Bundling?

Tags: c#, asp.net, system.web.optimization

My solution consists of several WebApplications who share the same static content.

I've been recently been using Microsoft ASP.NET Optimization Framework for bundeling these files.

The problem is I only have one Global.asax file where I register all the bundles, for instance:

```
var jqueryBundle = new ScriptBundle("~/Scripts/jquery");
        jqueryBundle.Include(new string[] { 
    "~/static/js/jQuery/jquery-1.11.2.js",
    "~/static/js/jQuery/jquery-ui.js"});
```

Then on my Master page I have :

```
<asp:PlaceHolder ID="phBundle" runat="server">
    <%: System.Web.Optimization.Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery") %>
</asp:PlaceHolder>
```

To reference this files on any other aplication I have to use the full path:

```
<%: System.Web.Optimization.Scripts.Render("/websites/MainApp/Scripts/jquery") %>
```

The problem with this is that, when running in debug mode,  the second application static files appear as bundles and
not as single/separated files.

Also, when running in release mode, files are fettched without a hash (meaning if they are cached they won't be updated)

MAIN APP
[image: Get static files on the 1st application]

SECONDARY APP
[image: Get static files on the 2nd application]

I want to solve this problem wihtout copying all the static files between every project and registering them individually in the Global.asax (currently only the main app has a Global.asax)